# Desktop Application gridview cell values lock alternate according to cell values

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I have a grid, It have 6 columns(item name,min quantity,max quantity,max amout,max amount,Discount).

**Requirement**

When I select **min Quantity**, **max Quantity column** will Disable And its Value become Zero,when i select **min amount ,max amout column** will Disable and vice Versa. When i enter min value in quantity then row of grid contain max value from first row.

Comment: if u understand my question give me answer p/z

Comment: And What have you tried?

Comment: i fail to understand wat i do

Answer (score 0):

```
/* You can use grid's cell validating event.  
 ColMinimumQuantity, ColMaximumQuantity, ColMinimumAmount, ColMaximumAmount are grid's column name
 you can set them in Grid Properties. */

private void dataGridView1_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.OwningColumn.Name.ToUpper().ToString() == "ColMaximumQuantity")
    {
        dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["ColMinimumQuantity"].Value = "0";
        dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["ColMaximummQuantity"].ReadOnly = false;
        dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["ColMinimummQuantity"].ReadOnly = true;
    }

    if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.OwningColumn.Name.ToUpper().ToString() == "ColMaximumAmount")
    {
        dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["ColMinimumAmount"].Value = "0";
        dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["ColMaximummQuantity"].ReadOnly = false;
        dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["ColMinimummQuantity"].ReadOnly = true;
    }

    if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.OwningColumn.Name.ToUpper().ToString() == "ColMinimumAmount")
    {
        dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["ColMaximumAmount"].Value = "0";
        dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["ColMiniimumAmount"].ReadOnly = false;
        dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["ColMaximumAmount"].ReadOnly = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! It's always better to provide a short description for a sample code to improve the post accuracy :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use grid's cell validating event.
ColMinimumQuantity, ColMaximumQuantity, ColMinimumAmount, ColMaximumAmount are grid's column name
you can set them in Grid Properties.